# Xamarin Forms UWP: Access all files within a folder

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

My application needs to access all (.mp3) files in a folder

```
var folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads\\Test\\Folder\\");
var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
```

But I get a "`Folder` access is denied"

I added the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability to the **Package.appxmanifest**, but no luck.

I also tried other folders, like `SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` and `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`, but again, no luck

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I use your code to access downloads folder, it also display:Folder access is denied.

But I use the following code to access Downloads folder, you can take a look:

```
private  void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirSearch(@"C:\Users\cherryb\Downloads\test");
    }
    public async void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {

        var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(sDir);

        foreach (var Folder in await folder.GetFoldersAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Folder.Name);              
        }


    }
```

You need to add this namespace

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
```

and update the IgnorableNamesSpaces

```
 IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap"
```

add a new capability

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />    
<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

More detailed info about file system access, you can take a look:

https://www.jocheojeda.com/2019/01/26/xamarin-forms-uwp-uap-broad-file-system-access/

There are one sample you can get:

https://github.com/egarim/Xamarin-Forms-UWP-UAP-Broad-File-System-Access